# Create a workflow solution to send an email on new list item creation in SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, workflow, office365

How to create a Workflow solution in Visual Studio 2013 to send an email on new list item creation in SharePoint O365 list.

Comment: Do you need to use vs to develop that workflow? Basic workflow in SPD is OK

Comment: I need workflow as a VS solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could send email messages from a workflow in sharepoint-hosted app :

1. Create SharePoint Hosted APP Project.
2. Create list workflow. Select the list on which you want to run the workflow,  and creating new "WorkflowToHistory" and "WorkflowTaskList" for storing workflow history and task info.
3. Choose the starting options accordingly. In this, you could to start the workflow automatically when an item added.
4. Complete the workflow ,you should expand the SP – Utilities tab on the Toolbox then drag the Email activity onto the designer to send the email .For this part ,please click [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2013/09/18/step-by-step-sending-email-messages-from-a-workflow-in-an-app-for-sharepoint-2013/) for how to detail steps and refer to [this link](http://thesharepointhelper.blogspot.sg/2015/04/sharepoint-apps-sending-email.html) for a video .
5. Deploy the app and testing .

In addition , since we are creating workflows in SharePoint Apps. However this has been limited to the workflows living exclusively within the AppWeb where the app was installed. If you wanted to have the workflow run in a regular SharePoint site, such as a Team Site, or a non-AppWeb site , for example, deploy Workflows to Host Web , you could deploy as [Integrated Workflow Apps](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/sharepoint-online-integrated-workflow-apps-workflows-as-apps-in-the-hostweb). Click [this article](http://www.vrdmn.com/2014/09/integrated-workflow-apps-deploy.html) about how to deploy site/List Workflow to host web , you could focus on list workflow part .

Comment: there is only design view while developing using VS, no code view right?